# remove white space between cards lines from bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to remove the space between the cards (vertically). In other words, I would like the cards to use all the available space. I'm OK to use a plugin if necessary but I can't find anything on that (maybe I didn't use the right keywords on google)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h1>Lorem</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h1>Lorem<br>ipsum</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h1>Lorem<br>ipsum<br>dolor<br>sit<br>met<br>a</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h1>hello</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

[screenshot of the desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf31G.png)

Comment: What you want is to create a Mansory Layout, it is possible with CSS only but the best ones are javascript libraries. Look it up

Comment: You tagged this question with CSS but did not provide any. Please update the snippet I edited

Comment: @gugateider> Mansory is what I was looking for. Thhanks

Answer (score 1):

This was a big issue with some earlier versions of bootstrap. We used to apply a min-height to all the cards, so they would somewhat line up.

Otherwise, I think it's just easier use CSS grid. CSS grid really changed the game. You can put together layouts in minutes without having to deal with all the framework issues.

https://jsfiddle.net/n7Ltxjdc/#&togetherjs=B4bEDiotHC

```
<style>
    .parent{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-gap: 1rem;
        background: #f7f7f7
    }
    .parent .card{
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 6px 24px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) 0px 0px 0px 1px;
        padding: 0 1rem; box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        .parent{grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;}
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
        .parent{grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;}
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        .parent{grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;}
    }
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="card">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit. 
        Proin a imperdiet sapien. Aliquam at massa nec 
        nisi facilisis ullamcorper mattis et lacus. 
        Morbi aliquam ac nisi et posuere. Mauris dictum 
        tortor id magna convallis pulvinar.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit. 
        Proin a imperdiet sapien. Aliquam at massa nec 
        nisi facilisis ullamcorper mattis et lacus. 
        Morbi aliquam ac nisi et posuere. Mauris dictum 
        tortor id magna convallis pulvinar.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit. 
        Proin a imperdiet sapien. Aliquam at massa nec 
        nisi facilisis ullamcorper mattis et lacus. 
        Morbi aliquam ac nisi et posuere. Mauris dictum 
        tortor id magna convallis pulvinar.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit. 
        Proin a imperdiet sapien. Aliquam at massa nec 
        nisi facilisis ullamcorper mattis et lacus. 
        Morbi aliquam ac nisi et posuere. Mauris dictum 
        tortor id magna convallis pulvinar.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Although I'm not sure, maybe bootstrap 4 fixed this issue and I just haven't received the update.